# Share the same text in UILabel between several classes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uilabel

I have an NSString in one class, a UILabel in another class and the 3rd UILabel in my 3rd class. They are all on 3 different views in IB.
I want my 1st class to save some string to NSString and I want my 2nd view UILabel to equal this NSString and my 3rd class' UILabel to equal my 2nd class' UILabel.
How do I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is your class hierarchy? is it using navigation controller? also do you want some constant type string?

Comment: they are all modal views, except the first which is a navigation controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common question with a common pattern for a solution.

Create a [model class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) to hold your string. Instantiate an object of this class in your application delegate (perhaps in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`), and pass it along to all three of your view controllers. Use [Key-Value Observing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) on your model class by your sub-view controllers, so they get alerted to any changes in the model (i.e. changes to the string).